# Wampserver - page is displaying differently depending on how I visit it?

Tags: html, wampserver

To get used to using server software (and to make it easier to test PHP scripts), I thought I'd host a website myself. I successfully installed Wampserver, and I can visit the page by going to either file:///C:/wamp/www/site/index.php or 127.0.0.1/site/index.php. Going to the former displays the page how I want it; http://i49.tinypic.com/19xqn6.png. But when I visit it at the latter, it displays differently (the "logged in" notice moves down); http://i49.tinypic.com/sy9feg.png. Why does it display differently?

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at some code from the page. Maybe some javascript files referenced relative to the root of the website which means javascript isn't loaded when you open your page directly as a file.

Comment: If the site is on the internet, a link would be nice. Does it happen in all browsers? If you open the Developer Tools in Chrome, does it say there are any errors?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `file:///C:` you won't be running in the server environment. This means any server side code won't work (such as PHP code). You want to use `127.0.0.1/site` or `localhost/site`.

When you use `file:///C:` all of your html and javascript will be displayed properly, because that's done client side.  Anything that is supposed to run server side, such as php won't execute.

Comment: Thanks.  I know this, and I still occasionally make the same mistake.